# Is there a general rule for proving that an equation has no analyticial solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, transcendental-equations, transcendence-theory

Somebody asked this here:

[Prove that an equation has no elementary solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982984/prove-that-an-equation-has-no-elementary-solution)

But so far there is no response. The little math I know I have learnt it myself so I dont have a big picture of things. I was wondering if there is a general rule for showing that a function has no analytical solution. For instance:

> $$10=x+\ln(x)$$

How can I find the value of $x$? How can I show this is not possible with simple mathematics? Even with no simple math, there is some tool to do it?

Comment: It really depends on exactly what you mean by "analytical". It is often the case that I can't write an answer in terms of the "usual" elementary functions, but can compute it just as well as I can compute sine.

Comment: Closed form is relative term. For instance $\sqrt 2$ is only a closed form because you allow the square root symbol. The number $\sin(1)$ is only closed form because you consider $\sin$ to be one of your standard functions. In your particular equation, the solution is $W\left(e^{10}\right)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (this is one that not everyone would consider to be an elementary function, but some people find important enough to add it to that class). See [special functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) for more.

Comment: The value of the solution can be found numerically, not differently for how one would 'find' $\sin(1), e$ or $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are no algebraic solutions to this problem frankly I can't answer the last bit of your question however I can demonstrate an algebraic-ish solution. So basically there is something called Lambert W function and the function is shown by a capital W.

$W(c)=x , c= xe^x$

It is a pretty useful function which allows us to solve equations like  $x^x=5$.
Even though it is not an algebraic solution it still gives us an insight about what we're dealing with.

In the given example we can apply the following like this:
$10-lnx=x$

$lne^{10}-lnx=x$

$ln{e^{10} \over x}=lne^x$

${e^{10} \over x} = e^x$

$e^{10} =xe^x$

$W(e^{10})=x\approx 7.9294$

You can find the values for the given input on Lambert W Function by using Wolfram Alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=productlog(e%5E10)